# any docs for all nodejs event API?

Tags: node.js, documentation

I saw some code snippet like below:

```
process.stdin.on('keypress', function(c, key){          
if (key && 'enter' == key.name) {
```

But sadly I couldn't find anything about how to use `keypress` event in `node`'s docs. Obviously it's different from `keypress` event in browsers. Moreover there is nothing introducing what `key` object is, so I don't know how to use `key.xxx` or `key.name == xxx` to detect which key user is pressing.

What do I miss? There must be somewhere I can found how to use `node`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The node documentation seems quite lacking in that regard like you mentioned.

The only reference I found was when going through the source for the ['readline'-module](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/readline.js#L840):

```
function emitKey(stream, s) {
    var ch,
    key = {
        name: undefined,
        ctrl: false,
        meta: false,
        shift: false
    },
```

and so on, basically the name, if ctrl is pressed, if shift is pressed, and some meta.

There's no doubt the docs needs some work :)

Comment: +1 for reading the source. At this point in node.js' lifetime this is really the best way to get an understanding of it's APIs.